# How to find which Graphic API, process is using?

Tags: android, linux, graphics, opengl-es, vulkan

Some apps and games can use multiple graphic APIs like OpenGLES or Vulkan, each at one time, like PUBG™ Mobile or CoD™ Mobile that using OpenGLES and Vulkan but you can choose which api use during process runtime.
I tried `lsof -p <pid> | grep -i -e gles -e vulkan` and it gives me both `*GLES.so` and `libvulkan.so` which means they are not loaded at runtime but they are linked at compile time.
Question: How can I find out which API is the process using and calling its functions to renders the frames under the linux? (android is basically a linux based OS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to attach a debugger or insert an API layer to monitor which API's draw calls are being used. You could do the same with a sampling profiler. The Android UI framework which is present in all on-screen applications uses GLES also, so you'd need to watch out for that. (Though in a full-screen game the UI framework shouldn't be doing anything except maybe a few setup calls at launch.) All of that requires that the app be debuggable.

Comment: Exactly, I was thinking about Riru since i installed it along with magisk I can inject code into process or I can use frida. I dont know which is the best way but I think thats the way.